# Singleton getting destroyed

Tags: c++, singleton, game-engine

I'm writing a class with methods that can be overriden, the problem is when I construct the class that overrides the methods, the singleton works while the class with the overriden methods stills alive. How can I keep the new class alive?

The base class:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <string>

class File
{
    static File *singleton;

public:
    File();
    ~File();

    virtual char *read(std::string path);
    virtual void write(std::string path, const char *buffer);

    static File *get_singleton();
};
```

```cpp
#include "File.h"
#include "../OS.h"

File *File::singleton = nullptr;

File::File()
{
    File::singleton = this;
}

File::~File()
{
}

char *File::read(std::string path)
{
    return nullptr;
}

void File::write(std::string path, const char *buffer)
{
}

File* File::get_singleton()
{
    return singleton;
}
```

The code that I'm using:

```
#pragma once

#include <core/os/File.h>

class File_SDL : public File
{
public:
    File_Handler();

    char *read(std::string path) override;
    void write(std::string path, const char *buffer) override;
};
```

__

```
#include "File_Handler.h"

#include <core/OS.h>

File_Handler::File_Handler() : File()
{
}

char *File_Handler::read(std::string path)
{
}

void File_Handler::write(std::string path, const char *buffer)
{
}
```

How to reproduce the bug:

```
void other_function()
{
    //Crashes
    File::get_singleton()->write("file.txt", "Hello, World!");
}

void main()
{
   File_Handler handler = File_Handler();
   other_function();
}
```

The singleton should work normally since they are static, but the only thing I get is just a access violation at address.

Comment: Your "singleton" is not a singleton: constructor is `public` and so you might create several instances. (In your sample, you don't create any instance BTW).

Comment: Please post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem (including the derived class that you mentioned - _"the class that overrides the methods"_). BTW - since your constructor is public multiple instances of `File` can be created.

Comment: See [Meyers' singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: Since you are able to create many instances of your class, it is not a singleton.   All your class does is ensure that the so-called `singleton` member points at the last instance created.   Which will be problematical if the last instance created ceases to exist since code that subsequently calls `get_singleton()` will receive a dangling reference.

Comment: Is there any way in which I can keep the last instance alive? because no, I don't have multiple instances, it is just one, but I keep that format to create multiple implementations depending on the platform.

Comment: Change `File::get_singleton` to return a `File&` instead. The body should just be `{static File instance; return instance;}`. Remove the member `singleton` entirely. This will give you a singleton that is initialized upon the first time you call `get_singleton` and is guaranteed to live thoughout the execution of the program. You can put whatever platform-specific stuff around the constructor because regardless of how the constructor is written, the `get_singleton` as designed above is guaranteed to work.

Comment: _Side note:_ When you wrote: `class File_SDL : public File`, did you mean: `class File_Handler : public File`?

Comment: Side note: Avoid using singletons. They are just glorified global variables and have all the same downsides (and more) that global variables do. No sane program needs singletons and 20 years down the line maintenance programmers will thank you for not having to clean out your singletons. The singleton pattern is a *bad* pattern, don't use it.

Answer (score -1):

The problem I had was that the singletons that I declared don't live enough, so to solve this, I put the short-life singletons inside a singleton that lives through the entire program.

Comment: So the answer is to move the problem elsewhere?

Comment: The problem wasn't moved, what I did was just change the lifetime of the instance.